# Vue3 Typescript props either show error or nothing at all

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-component, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to use the default Quasar card component to show data coming from props. However nothing ever shows up in my component and i get a bunch of different errors depending on what I try.

Latest ones were "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'character')" and "defineProps() is a compiler-hint helper that is only usable inside  of a single file component. Its arguments should be compiled away and passing it at runtime has no effect"

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
<template>
<q-card class="my-card" flat bordered>
    <q-card-section horizontal>
      <q-img class="col-5" src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/parallax2.jpg" />
      <q-card-section> {{ props.character }} </q-card-section>
    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, defineProps, PropType } from 'vue';
import { Character } from './models';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CardComponent',

  setup() {
    const props = defineProps({
      character: Object as PropType<Character> | null,
    });
    return {
      props,
      lorem: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, blah blah blah',
    };
  },
});
</script>
<style lang="sass" scoped>
.my-card
  width: 100%
  max-width: 350px
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defineProps()` is used in [SFC script setup](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html). When you are using object syntax with a `setup()` function, [props are passed as the first argument to `setup()`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#accessing-props) and defined using the [props property](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#props).

So it should look something like this:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CardComponent',
  props: {
    character: Object as PropType<Character> | null,
  },
  setup(props) {
    return {
      props,
      lorem: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, blah blah blah',
    };
  },
});
```

Comment: Gonna test it as soon as I get home

Answer (score 1):

[I believe the answer from Moritz is correct](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props), but if you can't for some reason get that working, this is [a very simple example](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#definecomponent) of the Quasar framework, Parallax component, using props without PropType.

```js
const props = { message: "This text will show using {{ props.message  }} " };
const app = Vue.createApp({
  props: ["message"],
  setup() {
    return {
      props,
      name: "Quasar Framework"
    };
  }
});

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} });
app.mount("#q-app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.12.2/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh;" data-message="This  text won't show, neither will line #7.">
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    {{message}}
    <q-parallax>
      <template v-slot:media>
        <img src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/parallax2.jpg" style="opacity: .75 ">
      </template>

      <template v-slot:content="scope">
        <div class="absolute column items-center" :style="{
            opacity: 0.75 + (1 - scope.percentScrolled) * 0.55,
            top: (scope.percentScrolled * 60) + '%',
            left: 0,
            right: 0
          }">
          <img src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/logo-v2/svg/logo-mono-white.svg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px">
          <div class="text-h3 text-purple-5 text-center">{{ name }} </div>
          <div class="text-h4 text-center text-green-6">{{ props.message }}</div>
          <div class="text-h6 text-orange-3 text-center">
            v{{ $q.version }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </q-parallax>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen if the code isn't running/showing Parallax on Stack Overflow:

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/treckstar_/pen/MWzVjLb)

Edit: Figure I'd share this as well. [I initially tried to get this example working using the Vue playground but didn't ever end up rendering](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).
But this is the full code I believe here, with the `Character` model being assumed:

```
<template>
  <q-card class="my-card" flat bordered>
    <q-card-section horizontal>
      <q-img class="col-5" src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/parallax2.jpg" />
      <q-card-section> {{ props.character }} </q-card-section>
    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { QCard } from 'quasar';
import { defineComponent, defineProps, PropType } from 'vue';

interface Character {
  name: string
}

// you can try this way as well
// const props = defineProps({
//   character: Object as PropType<Character>
// })
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'CardComponent',
  props: {
    character: Object as PropType<Character>
  },
  components: {
  QCard
  },
  setup(props) {
    return {
      props,
      lorem: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, blah blah blah',
    };
  },
});
</script>
<style scoped>
.my-card {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
}
</style>
```